# SQL - Finding Percent Of a Total and subtracting to get two new totals

Tags: sql

In my SQL course I'm trying to answer a problem in which i'm being asked to find X% of a Total then subtracting that result from the original total to produce another result. Then putting these results (the X% of the total and the total-X% of total) in two new columns.

Example: We need to know how much money we owe Tom and Ted. We have total up sales to $1,000,000.00. We owe Tom 75% of that total. The remainder goes to Ted.

I can't seem to find anything in my readings/videos about this nor a google search that isn't an answers that produces ratios or comparing to other records in the table. Also, not sure about how to get the results into their own columns. Thanks for any advice!

Example of what I got so far:

```
SELECT SUM(Sale_Amount) From Order_Table
```

Now I have to find the % of that SUM then subtract it from the SUM and push both results to two new columns, one for the percent of the SUM(Sale_Amount) and one for the remainder.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: so far i can find the total, i do not know how to find the percent of that total nor how to take that percentage and subtract it from the total and the push those results to their own column. sorry, i dont know what to do or say to make that any clearer than i already have. I just have to show the query used to arrive at my answer. besides what i already talked about, ive exhausted my research options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given it's an SQL course (and it's not 100% clear what's being asked), I'm not going to give you the total answer, but I'll give you components but you'll need to understand them to put them together.

In SQL, you can

- Get totals using `SUM` and `GROUP BY`
- Do normal maths e.g., `SELECT 10000 * 60/100` to get percentages of totals
- 'Save' results by a) having columns/fields to save them in, and b) `UPDATE` those fields with relevant data

Note if you're not saving data, and simply reporting them, you can just add those to a SELECT statement e.g., `SELECT 100000 AS Total, 100000 * 0.75 AS Toms_Share, 100000 * 0.25 AS Teds_Share`.

Comment: Thank you! the normal maths example is exactly what i needed to get the answer i was needing! No where online did it just show that without suggesting ratios or comparisons

Comment: No worries at all. It felt like that was the problem. Once you get experience with SQL you just 'know about it', but may never be told to someone new.